# AttributeError: 'Program' object has no attribute 'file'

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
class Program:
    def Main(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        filepath = str(fname[0])
        fileObject = filepath.split('/')
        file = fileObject[len(fileObject) - 1]

    def image(self, Main):
        img1 = cv2.imread(Main.file())
```

i want to put in `img1` the `file` from function `Main()` but i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in image
    img1 = cv2.imread(Main.file())
AttributeError: 'Program' object has no attribute 'file'
```

Comment: do you get error or what? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: i guess `i - ui.Image_to_hide()` should be `i = ui.Image_to_hide()`

Comment: I fix  `i - ui.Image_to_hide()` to `i = ui.Image_to_hide()` but after the result is i get the Open image File Window to browse image and the 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final_test.py", line 127, in Encrypt
    img1 = cv2.imread(u.pixmap())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pixmap'`

Comment: @GaGoLL please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc i change and edit the code

Comment: @GaGoLL No, that is not an MRE; please read the content of the link.

Comment: @eyllanesc how is it now?

Comment: We can't see where are you calling `Program`, so that's why your example is still not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

There are some weird things in your code as far as I can see:

1. I don't know how you're calling the `image` method, but it currently receives a `Main` value. Correct me if I'm wrong since this is pure speculation, but I think you wanted to call the `Main` method of `Program`. If so, that's not how you do it. You can refactor it as:

```py
class Program:
    def Main(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        filepath = str(fname[0])
        fileObject = filepath.split('/')
        file = fileObject[len(fileObject) - 1]

    # Remove Main from method signature, since it's a method from Program
    def image(self):
        # Call Main from the self object
        img1 = cv2.imread(self.Main.file())
```

2. You're calling `self.Main.file()` inside the `image` method. Since `Main` is a method and it does not have another method called `file`, it'll throw a `AttributeError`. Another pure speculation, but I think you wanted to access the variable `file` inside the `Main` method. If so, that's not how you do it. You can't access a variable inside another method, but you can access a value returned by that method. You can refactor your `Main` to return the file that you want (and rename it to a proper name, such as `get_file`):

```py
class Program:
    # Rename Main to a more descriptive name
    def get_file(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        filepath = str(fname[0])
        fileObject = filepath.split('/')
        # Return it so we can access this value outside of it
        return fileObject[len(fileObject) - 1]

    def image(self):
        # Access the file returned by get_file
        # Since this a method of Program, call it using the self object
        file = self.get_file()

        # Use the returned value
        img1 = cv2.imread(file)
```

3. Some minor improvements:

```py
class Program:
    # Rename Main to a more descriptive name
    def get_file(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        filepath = str(fname[0])
        fileObject = filepath.split('/')
        # You can remove use -1 as index to the last value
        return fileObject[-1]

    def image(self):
        file = self.get_file()
        # Probably you want to return the variable below
        return cv2.imread(file)
```

**Full code:**

```py
class Program:
    def get_file(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        filepath = str(fname[0])
        fileObject = filepath.split('/')
        return fileObject[-1]

    def image(self):
        file = self.get_file()
        return cv2.imread(file)
```